# C# Textbox to Textblock on other page

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am new to coding and stackoverflow, so bear over with me :)

As discussed here I tried to implement the solution, but it returned two errors
[TextBox input to TextBlock in other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723471/textbox-input-to-textblock-in-other-page)

My code on button click looks like this: (MainPage.xaml.cs)

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        connecting resultpage = new connecting(nicktext.Text, seiptext.Text);
        NavigationService.Navigate(resultpage);
    }
```

Though it returns these two errors:

1. Error    2   Argument 1: cannot convert from '---.connecting' to 'System.Uri'
2. Error    1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate(System.Uri)' has some invalid arguments

I'm sorry if the answer is obvious, but I've tried what I can...

**EDIT:** Added the new code as requested: (connecting.xaml.cs)

```
public partial class connecting : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public connecting(string nickname, string serverip)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is connecting a class? If yes can you pasye its code?

Comment: It is a problem with your connection class I think, please provide more code

Comment: The `Navigate` method wants the type `System.Uri` but you're giving it an instance of type `connecting`. Does `connecting` expose a Uri property or anything? Let us see the code for `connnecting`.

Comment: I have updated the code as requested, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

NavigationService.Navigate needs an uri to navigate to the page. You need to pass the uri of the connecting page. For example if connecting page(class) is in folder /Pages/connecting.xaml, for navigating to that page you need this code:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new System.Uri("/Pages/connecting.xaml", UriKing.Relative);
```